# Markdown in Careers Experience Responsibilities does not render

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, markdown, cv

In my CV on careers I have this entry in my first experience responsibilities field:

```
 Project management and development of
 framework for model driven development
 in Delphi. Look for Atlas 2 framework
 at [Opus](www.opus.ch).
```

As you can see on [my public CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ralphrickenbach), the link is not rendered.

This does not work either

```
 Project management and development of
 framework for model driven development
 in Delphi. Look for Atlas 2 framework
 at [Opus][1].

  [1]: www.opus.ch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we require the http:// in front of all URLs

Comment: The life preview doesn't, sadly enough.